# dynamically creating view inside another view in mvc 3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have downloaded an html file as stream object and and and i have to render a partial view in a particular  tag inside the html file . All the html file along with the partial view will be shown as a preview inside a view under a preview tag section. 
I am able to find a div tag inside the html file and i set  the user control  div's inner html. The code i used is

```
 header.InnerHtml = " <%:Html.RenderPartial(" + "\"/ViewUserControl1" + "\"); %> ";
```

where "header" is the id of the div . and pass entire string to(html along with usercontrol ) to view using

```
<div id="Preview" >
    <%=ViewData["Preview"] %>
</div>
```

But the div preview dosent render user control. only html file preview is shown. Any ideas will be grately appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Strings will not be parsed as view code unless you do a bunch of extra work - that would be a huge security hole. Even if you set up parsing of the string, the rest of the html won't be valid view code.

The best option would be to just use a token in the html - "{VIEW}" or something like that - and do a string replace in your view using the template html and view name properties from the model.

Also note the difference between Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial - one returns a string, the other writes to the output stream and returns nothing.

Comment: when i viewed the source of the view page, i could find every thing as such in the html file but inside the div 'header' the "<%:Html.RenderPartial("ViewUserControl1" "); %>" is displayed in html comment format. Can you plase explain using token in html .and string replace in the view... Thanks